# Extracting  from XML using Regex

Tags: php, regex

Need a regular expression to catch the everything nested in target tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<target>
"<x id="c400c8394f0a"  pid="NLCaption" name="NLCaption" />Caption"
</target>

<target />

<target><x id="a1e6b03cb682"  pid="NLSheets" name="NLSheets" />Sheets"</target>

</data>
```

Thanks to Brettz, Who helped me in writing the following regular expression

```
$pattern = "@<target(?:\s.*?)?>(.*?)</target\s*>@s";
```

This regular expression does the job and help me getting all the content. But the only problem is that it also catches the  `<target />` tag as well.

I wan to modify the regular expression that donot catches unpaired tag. i.e. `<target />`

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tagname = 'target';
$pattern = "@<$tagname(?:\s.*?!/)?>(.*?)</$tagname\s*>@s";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $data->target[0];
```

[Here is an example of using SimpleXML with your XML](http://codepad.org/AorEi4iJ)

Comment: Thanks! you might be right. But right now I am need to fix this regular expression.. Basically, I wan to neutralize the nested tags in a target node.

Comment: @Shahid Parsing XML using an actual XML Parser is a lot simpler (as you are experiencing) that using Regex to do the same think ... use the right tool for the job ...

Comment: I need to create a string like as follow and this will also need to written to actual file (i.e. update its content) and I was not able to do this using DOM parsing

`<target>
&quot;&lt;x id=&quot;c400c8394f0a&quot;  pid=&quot;NLCaption&quot; name="NLCaption" /&gt;Caption&quot;
</target>`

Comment: @Shahid put your required output in your question (formatted of course).... with SimpleXML everything in the XMl is accesible - you just need to extract it and output to the desired format

Comment: How can get the inner content + nested tags of target node in one variable??? So that I can then convert the values to htmlentites equivalent. 

`"<x id="c400c8394f0a"  pid="NLCaption" name="NLCaption" />Caption"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "(?<=<target>).+(?=</target>)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the end of the first section to only allow spaces and no other characters:

`<target\s*>(.*?)</target\s*>`

The xml parser is almost certainly still the right long-term solution, but this is a quick way to get your code working.

Comment: `$tagname = 'target';`
`$pattern = "<$tagname\s*>(.*?)</$tagname\s*>";`
`$content = preg_replace_callback($pattern,  html_entities, $xml);`

Unknown modifier '(' in.....???

Comment: I want to only include in first section that `[^/]` i.e. `/` cannot occur in this section so how can do this???

Comment: Check the syntax for preg_replace: change your code to `$pattern = "#<" . $tagname . "\s*>(.*?)</" . $tagname . "\s*>#is";`