# PHP regular expression match a paired tag but not unpaired tag

Tags: php, regex

I am extracting a nested content of a tag. I have written a regular expression that works perfectly on my local machine (WAMP) PHP Version 5.3.8, Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version   - 4.7.1

```
$tagname = 'mytag';
$pattern = "@<$tagname(?:\s.*?!/)?>(.*?)</$tagname\s*>@s";
```

but the same regular expression is not working properly on my live machine with configuration of PHP Version 5.2.11, Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version- 4.4.4
and Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check = on.

Please help in modifying this regular expression that it start work on live site.

This regular expression match `<mytag></mytag>` and it is not matching `<mytag />`.

Update: Thanks for your suggestions and responses.

I updated that regular expression a bit and it worked for me. You can use this regular expression whenever you want get inner content (nested tags and text). No matter how your tag is arranged and no matter how many attributes it has.

Comment: If this is some XML-like language you are trying to parse, consider using a decent XML parser.

Comment: Agreed with Gumbo. I'm a big fan of regular expressions, but for all but the simplest of cases, if you're dealing with XML or HTML, you're going to find life a lot easier if you use [SimpleXML](http://jp2.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to do the parsing for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting  from XML using Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250381/extracting-from-xml-using-regex)

Comment: Don't ask the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to Put somwhere, something like:

```
(?:</$tagname>|/>)
```

Comment: Thanks changed it as `$pattern = "@<$tagname(?:\s!/.*?)?>(.*?)</$tagname\s*>@s";`  and it worked ....